# Debian won't shut down completely

Tags: debian, shutdown

My Debian wheezy (64-bit) won't fully shut down. What I mean by this is that when I select "`Shut Down...`" from the menu the screen goes blank but the power button remains lit and front fan keeps working. Only after I hold down the power button for a 5 sec or so it actually shuts down fully...

Did some googling and usually power managment is blamed in these kind of situations. Here are some suspicious messages related to power managment in my `/var/log/messages`, in order of appearance:

```
kernel: [    0.000000] ACPI Warning: FADT (revision 5) is longer than ACPI 2.0 version, truncating length 268 to 244 (20110623/tbfadt-288)
kernel: [    0.010862] x2apic not enabled, IRQ remapping init failed
kernel: [    0.485956] ACPI FADT declares the system doesn't support PCIe ASPM, so disable it
kernel: [    0.494932] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
kernel: [    0.546125] PCI: Using host bridge windows from ACPI; if necessary, use "pci=nocrs" and report a bug
kernel: [    0.747176] ERST: Table is not found!
kernel: [    0.747177] GHES: HEST is not enabled!
```

then there is few like the following two:

```
kernel: [    1.361930] ACPI Error: [DSSP] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20110623/psargs-359)
kernel: [    1.361934] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB_.PCI0.SAT0.SPT0._GTF] (Node ffff88040f4b5290), AE_NOT_FOUND (20110623/psparse-536)
```

There is nothing in the `kern.log` or `syslog` that relates to shutdown (in the kern.log there is point which I can identify as startup but messages preceding that point aren't related to shutdown. syslog doesn't seem to have any intresting messages at all). Here is the few messages from `messages` at the time I did last restart (early this morning):

```
Jul  3 01:03:49 shutdown[22028]: shutting down for system halt
Jul  3 01:04:49 kernel: imklog 5.8.11, log source = /proc/kmsg started.
Jul  3 01:04:49 rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="5.8.11" x-pid="2537" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
Jul  3 01:04:49 kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
Jul  3 01:04:49 kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
Jul  3 01:04:49 kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 3.2.0-4-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc version 4.6.3 (Debian 4.6.3-14) ) #1 SMP Debian 3.2.57-3+deb7u2
Jul  3 01:04:49 kernel: [    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-4-amd64 root=UUID=751d0e52-b064-4503-be7c-11270f8089e3 ro quiet
```

When executing `shutdown -h now` in the root terminal the result is the same (not full shutdown) but there is more info in the `syslog`:

```
Jul 3 14:58:04 shutdown[3929]: shutting down for system halt
Jul 3 14:58:04 init: Switching to runlevel: 0
Jul 3 14:58:05 minissdpd[3235]: received signal 15, good-bye
Jul 3 14:58:05 bluetoothd[3057]: Terminating
Jul 3 14:58:05 avahi-daemon[3055]: Got SIGTERM, quitting.
Jul 3 14:58:05 avahi-daemon[3055]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv6 with address fe80::beee:7bff:fe74:647d.
Jul 3 14:58:05 avahi-daemon[3055]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv4 with address 192.168.0.101.
Jul 3 14:58:05 pulseaudio[3683]: [pulseaudio] module-alsa-card.c: Failed to find a working profile.
Jul 3 14:58:05 pulseaudio[3683]: [pulseaudio] module.c: Failed to load module "module-alsa-card" (argument: "device_id="0" name="pci-0000_00_03.0" card_name="alsa_ca
```

and in `messages`:

```
Jul 3 14:58:04 shutdown[3929]: shutting down for system halt
Jul 3 14:58:05 kernel: [   90.616600] colord-sane[3886]: segfault at 18 ip 00007fa8dc5a2543 sp 00007fa8cb9808c0 error 6 in libc-2.13.so[7fa8dc529000+182000]
```

BTW there is also VirtualBox installed and following message is in the log
`kernel: [   38.497835] warning: VirtualBox uses 32-bit capabilities (legacy support in use)` but I don't think thats really the issue...

So I'm looking for suggestions how to fix this. Should I update some driver or update BIOS or...? I'm really not an Linux power user so please be as specific as possible when additional information is needed or when you suggest some solution.

My system info:

```
Release 7.5 (wheezy) 64-bit
Kernel Linux 3.2.0-4-amd64
GNOME 3.4.2
Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 0x209)
Experience: Fallback
```

```
ASUS UEFI BIOS Utility
Bios Version: 1005 x64 H87-PRO
Build date: 01/02/2014
ME Version: 9.0.2.1345
South Bridge Stepping: 05/C2
CPU: Intel Core i5-4670 @ 3.4GHz
```

Comment: Have you tried to look for log messages that occurred during the shutdown in `/var/log/syslog` or `/var/log/kern.log`? Maybe it logged something interesting when it failed to power down that could help to track this down.

Comment: Are you mounting any remote filesystems? Does it work if you disable networking before attempting to shut down?

Comment: @MartinvonWittich I edited my post with info about syslog and kern.log - nothing intresting in there as far as I see... perhaps I have to enable some debugging parameters to get more info? To `terdon`: no, I don't mount any remote filesystems. Only thing close to that is shared folders between host and virtualbox guests but I always shut down all VMs (and VBox GUI interface) before shutting down the host so that shouldn't be problem?

Comment: If you call `shutdown -h now` as root user, does it work? If you need more output, switching first to one of the consoles with e.g. "Ctrl-Alt-F1".

Comment: @jofel executed that command in root' terminal and there is more info in the logs now, see the update in the guestion. syslog suggest something wrong with the pulseaudio, messages have a segfault for colord-sane...

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue, I have no idea what is, to temporarily resolve this I created an alias in .bashrc.

`alias poweroff='su -c "'"systemctl poweroff"'"'`

`alias restart='su -c "'"systemctl reboot"'"'`

Comment: That works for you? In my system I get error `Failed to get D-Bus connection: No connection to service manager.`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot some double quotes. But yes, works for me. Surely you has booting with `init` instead `systemctl`. Do you have installed `systemd`

Comment: Yes, I use the default, ie init. I do have systemd installed (installed it about a year ago in an attempt to fix another problem) so I now pressed "e" in GRUB's menu and added `init=/bin/systemd` to appropriate line. After system came up I checked with `ps -A` that the proccess 1 is indeed `systemd` but when executing `poweroff` I still get the same behaviour, ie not complete shutdown. I fixed the quotes as you wrote so the command now executes without errors, but unfortunately it doesn't fix the problem...